# What cable do a need to connect a SATA SSD to a computer with eSATA and USB plugs?

Tags: usb, ssd, external-hard-drive, sata, esata

I have a laptop ([Dell Precision M 6700](http://www.dell.com/entreprise/p/precision-m6700/pd)) with an eSATA plug and some free USB ports. What type of cable do I need to plug the SATA SSD to the eSATA and power it? Is there a cable with eSATA on a side and data + power SATA plugs on the other side? I have looked on some seller websites but I don't know how this cable is named.

I already have an external USB hard drive enclosure, I can put in it a SATA drive in order to connect it through USB but I think it will be slower with USB interface instead of eSATA.

Edit: I found the [SATA 22 Pin to eSATA Data + USB Power Cable cable @ NewEgg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA5H61PS7723&cm_re=usb_to_sata_power-_-0ZF-0002-00006-_-Product) and [SATA 22 pin to eSATA USB @ Amazon.fr](http://www.amazon.fr/Vktech-adaptateur-connecteur-disque-broches/dp/B00DJ20PBK/). Is it the right type of cable? Will it deliver enough power to the SSD?

Comment: the newegg link should work if the drive is a 2.5" drive. the larger 3.5" drives require more power than USB can typically provide.

Comment: **What you need is what you already have**  Its not clear the reason you think it will be slower if you have an eSATA enclosure.

Comment: @BrandonB: this is a SSD 2.5" drive.

Comment: @Ramhound: this is a USB2 hard drive enclosure.

Comment: I am not sure you will notice a huge difference between eSATA and a USB 3.0 enclosure to be honest unless your talking about a SSD.  Why are you asking if a SATA to eSATA cable will provide enough power, of course it will, that's the entire point of the cable.

Comment: I presume you are looking at a cable in order to easily swap between multiple drives, however if this is for a single drive, I would recommend the following item because it was the only one I could find that supported USB3 and eSata for a 2.5" drive: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA3YB1JR5425

Comment: @Ramhound I don't have any USB3 port, I only have USB2 ports. So I think ESATA will be faster than USB2. And I prefer a simple ESATA cable than a ESATA enclosure, it's cheaper. The ESATA is not an ESATAP port, it doesn't provide power, so I need to get power from an USB port.

Comment: @BrandonB thanks but I don't need to swap drives. This enclosure is at least 5 times more expensive than a cable and the USB3 connection will be limited by the USB2 port.

Comment: This is all information we needed to know.  I shouldn't have to make statements then be told later the situation is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought a *SATA 22 pin to eSATA USB* and it worked.

Here is the cable model:

[image: SATA 22 pin to eSATA USB]

Image source: [Amazon](http://www.amazon.fr/Vktech-adaptateur-connecteur-disque-broches/dp/B00DJ20PBK/).